# ColdFusion: Extract information from a .msg file

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I would like to make an application where the user drags in a .msg file into my web app. Then ColdFusion would extract the following fields: name, sender email, subject, etc. and  pre-populate it in a form ready to be submitted. I have googled "read .msg ColdFusion" but can't seem to find any information. When I do a `FileRead()` I see only gibberish `ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ` because it's encrypted. Is this even possible? I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I am also open to trying a different approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @imthepitts mentioned, the file is not encrypted, it is just in binary. However, it is not enough to just load the bytes with `fileReadBinary()`. You need a tool that understands the [format of .msg files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/11/06/msg-file-format-part-1.aspx) and can parse its contents.

If you do a quick search, there are a bunch of tools capable of parsing .msg files (most are java or .net). One such tool is [POI's HSMF (Horrible Stupid Mail Format)](http://poi.apache.org/hsmf/). It is already built into CF. So you may want to start there.

Here is a quick and dirty example translated from the [HSMF examples](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hsmf/examples/Msg2txt.java?view=markup):

```
<cfscript>
    pathToFile = "c:/path/to/someMessage.msg";
    MAPIMessage = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.hsmf.MAPIMessage");
    message = MAPIMessage.init(pathToFile);


    try {
        WriteOutput("From: "& message.getDisplayFrom() &"<hr>");
        WriteOutput("To: "& message.getDisplayTo() &"<hr>");
        WriteOutput("CC: "& message.getDisplayCC() &"<hr>");
        WriteOutput("BCC: "& message.getDisplayBCC() &"<hr>");
        WriteOutput("Subject: "& message.getSubject() &"<hr>");
        WriteOutput("Body: "& message.getTextBody() &"<hr>");
    } catch (org.apache.poi.hsmf.exceptions.ChunkNotFoundException e) {
        WriteDump(e);
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me out. I also wanted to know what time the message was sent so I tried `getMessageDate()` however it gives me a wrong date. For example, mail sent yesterday `getMessageDate()` will return a date today. Any incite on this?

Comment: I do not see that method in CF10. Are you loading a newer version of POI? Just a guess, but maybe it cannot parse the date and just falls back on today. There *may* be an error message somewhere in the CF log files (Depends on the POI version ...) but you may want to check.

Answer (score 1):

`FileRead()` is for text files. If you're seeing gibberish, it's because it's a binary file. Try [`FileReadBinary()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d66.html).

Comment: I get `Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.`

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Are you sure you're passing a string into the function?

Comment: My code is bascially `FileReadBinary("upload/mail.msg")` that .msg is some kind of encrypted outlook mail file.

Comment: If the file is encrypted, how are you expecting coldfusion to know that and decrypt it?

Comment: @imthepitts, my vote for this answer put your reputation into 4 digits.  Jolly well done indeed and you owe me a beer.

Comment: It is not encrypted. It is just binary like imthepitts said.